# Formal definition of mesh.

Tags: geometry

For my master thesis, I need to have a formal definition of a mesh, in a mathemathical point of view. So "geometric model described by vertices, edges and faces, ..." is not enough. And I can't seem to find good literature giving the definition.

Sorry if my request seems stupid.

Comment: A [simplicial complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex)?

Comment: You should indicate more clearly what kind of meshes you have in mind. Is it this:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh  ?

Comment: Sorry, yes it is a polygon mesh. I'm working with meshes used in Blender.

Comment: Perhaps the stl file format will help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_%28file_format%29

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the answer you are looking for may be in "Numerical methods for differential problem" of Quarteroni chapter 6

Comment: Your answer seems better suited as a comment, please move your post to the comment section.

Comment: @Rutie This could be a comment or you could answer the question here instead. I am interested in the OP´s question as well.